# Trying to print an array using an interface and its subclasses (one function)

Tags: php

I have a problem with this PHP code, as I try to get an array into a function under a class implementing the interface, but it ended up showing an error saying that I haven't declared a called function.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>  

<p><a href="selection.php">Back to selection php</a>

<?php

interface employee
{
    public function printout($wid, $arr);
}

class worker implements employee
{
    public function printout($wid, $arr)
    {
        for ($i=0; $i<7; $i++) {
        foreach ($arr[$wid][$i] as $val) {
            echo "$val <br>";
        }
    }

    }
}

$temp = new worker();
$id = "60800";
$warr = array();
$warr[$id][0] = "60800";
$warr[$id][1] = "Worker";
$warr[$id][2] = "Wang Mingchun";
$warr[$id][3] = "Day";
$warr[$id][4] = "NT$1000";
$warr[$id][5] = "N/A";
$warr[$id][6] = "N/A";
$temp = printout($id, $warr);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you mean `$temp->printout($id, $warr)`, the method from your class?

Comment: You don't have `printout` function. You have such method inside the class though.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved, guys.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>  

<p><a href="selection.php">Back to selection php</a>
<br>
<h1>Employee List</h1>
<h2>KEY LEGEND BELOW</h2>
<h3>ID__,__position__,__name__,__shift(workers)__,__rate(workers)__,__salary(foremen)__,__bonus(foremen)</h3>

<?php

interface employee
{
    public function printout($llid, $llarr);
}

class worker implements employee
{
    private $i;
    private $run = array();
    public function printout($llid, $llarr)
        {
        for ($i=0; $i<7; $i++) {
            echo ($llarr[$llid][$i]."__,__\t");
        }
        echo "<br>";
    }
}

class supervisor implements employee
{
    private $i;
    private $run = array();
    public function printout($llid, $llarr)
        {
        for ($i=0; $i<7; $i++) {
            echo ($llarr[$llid][$i]."__,__\t");
        }
        echo "<br>";
    }
}

//worker's part
$wtemp = new worker();
$id = "60800";
$warr = array();
$warr[$id][0] = "60800";
$warr[$id][1] = "Worker";
$warr[$id][2] = "Wang Mingchun";
$warr[$id][3] = "Day";
$warr[$id][4] = "NT$1000";
$warr[$id][5] = "n/a";
$warr[$id][6] = "n/a";
$wtemp->printout($id, $warr);

//supervisor's part
$stemp = new supervisor();
$id = "60800";
$sarr = array();
$sarr[$id][0] = "60800";
$sarr[$id][1] = "Worker";
$sarr[$id][2] = "Liu Tianhong";
$sarr[$id][3] = "n/a";
$sarr[$id][4] = "n/a";
$sarr[$id][5] = "NT$50000";
$sarr[$id][6] = "NT$10000";
$stemp->printout($id, $sarr);

?>

</body>
</html>
```